# Listen to methods (touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded) in UIView (subclass) and not parent UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, uikit

I'm new at iOS development.

I'm trying to create a Doodle App, I'm not using storyboards. My code is something like this:

- I have a `UIViewController` named **VWDashboard**.
- **VWDashboard** adds a `UIView` as a subview named **Doodle**.
- **Doodle** subview is supposed to be the screen where the doodle is going to be drawn, as Dashboard has other views and stuff... Dahsboard will "open" this **Doodle** view (add it as subview).
- To draw the doodle, I need to get `touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded` methods called on my UIView, but I'm getting it on my **VWDashboard**. In VWDashboard I have this:

  ```
  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      [doodleDelegate touchBegan:touches withEvent:event];
      NSLog(@"Dashboard: touchesBegan");
  }

  -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     [doodleDelegate touchMoved:touches withEvent:event];
      NSLog(@"Dashboard: touchesMoved");
  }

  -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      [doodleDelegate touchEnded:touches withEvent:event];
      NSLog(@"Dashboard: touchesEnded");
  }
  ```

In my `UIView`, these methods are declared (to override I think) and I have the code to draw the doodle there (I made a little demo on a UIViewController and worked).

When I touch the screen, all those logs can be seen, but methods on the subview are not being called.

I tried to create a Delegate that 'listens' the methods on **VWDashboard** and pass the data to my `UIView` Doodle so the doodle will be drawn in the corresponding `UIImageView`, etc. but does not work:

**VWDashboard.h**

```
    @class Doodle;
    @protocol DoodleDelegate <NSObject>

    - (void)touchBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
    - (void)touchMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
    - (void)touchEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

    @end

    @interface VWDashboard : VWBase {
        id <DoodleDelegate> delegate;
    }

    @property (retain, nonatomic) id <DoodleDelegate> delegate;

    @end
```

**Doodle.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "VWDashboard.h"

    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

    @interface Doodle : UIView <DoodleDelegate> {

        // Drawing
        CGPoint lastPoint;
        CGFloat red;
        CGFloat green;
        CGFloat blue;
        CGFloat brush;
        CGFloat opacity;
        BOOL mouseSwiped;
    }

    @end

    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**Doodle.m**

```
    #import "Doodle.h"
    #import "SCLAlertView.h"

    @implementation Doodle {

        UIImageView *canvasSignature, *canvasDoodle;
    }

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    /// renderUI ....

        return self;
    }

    -(void) renderUI...

    - (void)touchBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // Drawing code

    }
    - (void)touchMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        // Drawing code
    }
    - (void)touchEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Drawing code
    }

    @end
```

This is how I set the delegate in **VWDashboard**:

```
    Doodle *doodl = [[Doodle alloc] initWithFrame: _moduleLayoutActive.bounds];
    [self setDoodleDelegate:doodl];
    [_moduleLayoutActive addSubview: doodl];
```

Please! Any help I will really appreciate, thanks!

Comment: **ried to create a Delegate that 'listens' the methods on VWDashboard and pass the data to my UIView Doodle so the doodle will be drawn in the corresponding UIImageView, etc. but does not work* Where did you wrote the data passing code ?

Comment: I forgot about it, just edited... I put it on VWDashboard methods, calling the delegates methods @MidhunMP

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do....

```
(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch= [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == yourView)
    {
        //your code
    }

}

(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch= [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == yourView)
    {
        //your code
    }

}

(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch= [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == yourView)
    {
        //your code
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.